# Annotating chemical reactions typeset using the chemmacros package's reactions environment

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros, chemformula

I'm using the `reactions` environment in the [`chemmacros`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros?lang=en) package to typeset some chemical reactions. I would like to annotate each reaction with text. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{reactions}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
  (MnO2)_{surface} + Na+ + e- &<=> (MnOONa)_{surface}&{\footnotesize\text{surface adsorption}}\\
  MnO2 + Na+ + e- &<=> (MnOONa)&{\footnotesize\text{intercalation/deintercalation}}
\end{reactions}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Why is there no space between "surface" and "adsorption," and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets asked by users of `chemmacros` over and over but it's not `chemmacros` that's doing it. It is the macro `\ch` which is defined by the `chemformula` package. Said macro splits its contents at every space and then checks the remaining parts if they're formulas, or stoichiometric factors, or… have a look at `chemformula`'s manual for details.

The solution here is to use `~` for a space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{reactions}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
  (MnO2)_{surface} + Na+ + e- &<=> (MnOONa)_{surface} && \footnotesize surface~adsorption \\
  MnO2 + Na+ + e- &<=> (MnOONa) && \footnotesize intercalation/deintercalation
\end{reactions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way: you are not forced to use `chemformula` with `chemmacros`. You can also use `mhchem`, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{reactions}
\chemsetup{formula=mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
  (MnO2)_{surface} + Na+ + e- &<=> (MnOONa)_{surface} && \text{\footnotesize surface adsorption} \\
  MnO2 + Na+ + e- &<=> (MnOONa) && \text{\footnotesize intercalation/deintercalation}
\end{reactions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably the package does not support text mode. I changed your code a bit but the setup is almost identical. I put a space `\,` to separate the two words, and it works.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{reactions}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
  (MnO2)_{surface} + Na+ + e- &<=> (MnOONa)_{surface}&{\scriptsize\textup{surface\, adsorption}}\\
  MnO2 + Na+ + e- &<=> (MnOONa)&{\scriptsize\text{intercalation/deintercalation}}
\end{reactions}

\end{document}
```

[image]